# Processing huge json-array files with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have huge (~7GB) json array of relatively small objects.

Is there relatively simple way to filter these objects without loading whole file into memory?

**--stream** option looks suitable, but I can't figure out how to fold stream of [path,value] to original objects.

Comment: Small world. I've just come up against a similar problem. Out of interest, is the whitespace in your json file predictable? For example, large json arrays often use one line per top level array item?

Comment: If the file is already regularly formatted, then you might want to consider using text-wrangling tools to convert the file into a stream of small objects, which could then be processed using jq. If the file is not already suitably formatted, then if it is acceptable to use jq on the whole file just once, then you might consider using `jq .` to format the JSON to make it easy to convert into such a stream.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jq 1.5 has a streaming parser. The jq [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser) gives an example of how to convert a top-level array of JSON objects into a stream of its elements:

```
$ jq -nc --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))'
[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]
{"foo":"bar"}
{"foo":"baz"}
```

That may be enough for your purposes, but it is worthwhile noting that setpath/2 can be helpful.  Here's how to produce a stream of leaflets:

```
jq -c --stream '. as $in | select(length == 2) | {}|setpath($in[0]; $in[1])'
```

Further information and documentation is available in the jq manual:
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming

Comment: The `--stream` option looks promising, however I'm still unsure how to use it. For example, how will the streaming parser detect a missing closing bracket at the end?

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is intended way of solving my problem. Unfortunately looks like jq has a [bug](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/927) that prevents me of using it.


I ended up with writing own little json parser that did the same job.


Also I found that my simple python script that greps interesting entries works faster than jq (may be I use jq improperly). So I'm quite disapointed in this tool :(

Comment: @dim-an - My bad about the -n being necessary when inputs is used. The --stream option is new so I'm not surprised it is fairly slow.  As I mentioned elsewhere on this page, if I had been in your position (as indeed I have been), I would probably have simply clipped the first and last brackets, or focused on figuring out how to use jq once to wrangle your gigantic one-object JSON into a more manageable form.

Comment: ... or doing it the right way, like I've suggested! ;)

Comment: I need to do a `group_by(col)` on a json of around ~7GB size and the col contains around 3m distinct values. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @NishantKumar - I would suggest asking a new SO question, giving more specific details, as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dim-an any chance you could share your Python parser? I have similar use case to solve and your example would help me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @Jarek Oh, I'm afraid that script is lost long time ago and this parser was not generic in any way and was tuned for my special case. I suppose I searched for `}` char and considered it as object boundary (my json objects were really simple), then knowing object boundary I could do some processing (may be using builtin json parser). Once again it was throw-away parser that I used for some investigation.